# How can I have the following table side by side in the page?

Tags: tables

I have two tables like this :

```
\begin{figure}[t1]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf 1 dataset} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf Values}\\ \hline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf CellId} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf 1}  \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf Timestamp} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf 1383260400} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf cc} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf 39}  \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf In1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf 0.1467} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf Out1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf 0.1523}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf In2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf 0.1672}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf Out2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf 0.0512}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf Internet} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf 11.3291}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{{\bf (a)} 1 Data activity also called SMS-call dataset} 
\label{data-table a)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t2]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf 2 dataset} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf Values}\\ \hline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf UId} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf 38859420} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf TId} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf 12319812398} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf TTweet} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf Hi I'm in Milan} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf Lang} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf en} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf Date} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf 2013-11-08T16:22:34+00:00} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf Timestamp} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf  1383924154} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf Location} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf Milan} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf Coordinates} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf (45.46282657, 9.12790569)} \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{ {\bf (b)} 2 Dataset}
\label{data-table}
\end{figure}
```

How can I align those table in Latex in order to have them side by side in the page instead of havin them one above the other in the page ?

Comment: Please post working examples, not just fragments

Comment: The first thing i notice is the optional argument for the `figure`environment, which should raise an error. To be hoest, `\bf` was the first thing i noticed, right after that many `\multicolumn` commands.